# Complications adding Graphics to KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, java-2d

I'm trying to add shooting to my game, but I can't change my Player class to abstract or it will not work correctly, therefore I'm restricted to what I can do.

I've tried a million different ways to approach this, none worked. I've searched and searched and watched video tutorials to no avail. This is my last resort, I'm sure somebody can help me.

This is my first applet, but I'm not new to java. This isn't a 2D game. It's just a basic experiment I've been working on.

MainClass.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Benoit
 */
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass extends Applet implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    boolean running = true;
    Player p;
    Enemy e;
    Image dbImage;
    Graphics dbg;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    int mousex;
    int mousey;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        p = new Player(this);
        e = new Enemy(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            repaint();
            p.update(this);
            e.update(this, p);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.print("Error occured");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paint(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Game", 180, 20);
        p.paint(g, this);
        e.paint(g, this);
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Benoit
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class Player implements KeyListener {

    private int x = 200, y = 200, velX = 0, velY = 0;
    private URL url;
    private Image player;
    private Image playerimg;
    private Image Image;
    public boolean isShooting;


    public Player(MainClass mc) {
        url = mc.getDocumentBase();
        player = mc.getImage(url, "http://i563.photobucket.com/albums/ss75/belhelmiel/player-1.png");
    }

    public void update(MainClass mc) {
        mc.addKeyListener(this);
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, MainClass mc) {
        g.drawImage(player, x, y, mc);
        g.drawString("X:" + x + " Y:" + y, 10, 10);
        //g.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: {
                //This should make the player start shooting
                //I've tried a million different things
                //each one gave me some kind of problem primarily
                //because I can't set this class to abstract
                break;
            }

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                if (x >= 430) {
                    x = -40;
                }
                velX = 2;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                if (x <= -40) {
                    x = 430;
                }
                velX = -2;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP: {
                if (y <= -35) {
                    y = 430;
                }
                velY = -2;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: {
                if (y >= 400) {
                    y = -30;
                }
                velY = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: {
                //This should make the player stop shooting
                break;
            }

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                velX = 0;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                velX = 0;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP: {
                velY = 0;
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: {
                velY = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    void restart() {
        x = 200 - 38 / 2;
        y = 200 - 38 / 2;
    }
}
```

Enemy.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Benoit
 */
public class Enemy {

    private int x = 50, y = 50, Speed=3;
    private URL url;
    private Image enemy;

    public Enemy(MainClass mc) {
        url = mc.getDocumentBase();
        enemy = mc.getImage(url, "http://i563.photobucket.com/albums/ss75/belhelmiel/enemy.png");
    }

    public void update(MainClass mc, Player p) {
        x+=Speed;
        if(x<=0){
            Speed=3;
        }else if(x>=mc.getWidth()-33){
            Speed=-3;
        }

        Collision(p);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, MainClass mc) {
        g.drawImage(enemy, x, y, mc);
    }

    private void Collision(Player p) {
        int PX = p.getX();
        int PY = p.getY();

        if(PX-38 <= x && PX+38 >= x && PY-38 <= y && PY+38 >= y) {
            p.restart();
            System.out.print("Collision Detected");
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I can't provide you with enough information, I myself am at a lack of it as well because I cannot find anything helpful online after trying to figure this out for a longg time.

Summary:
I need to make some sort of bullets fire when the space bar is held down by the player. I know how to use keylistener but I can't use keylistener with the "Graphics g" without setting my Player class to abstract, which I cannot do or my game won't work. I've searched forever trying to figure out how to do this but to no avail. Sorry if this seems kind of odd, it may just be better for me to restart but I've been working on this for hours.

Comment: first applet ..game (animated rendering) .. watched video tutorials .. -- Combine & mix to form recipe for disaster.  Have you done game rendering in a frame, or better, panel?  I recommend swap `Applet` for `JFrame`, `paint()` for `paintComponent()` in a `JPanel` and `KeyListener` for key bindings.  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). And it is "Java applet" as opposed to "JAVA APPLET".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely work with keylistener and graphics without setting your player class to abstract. You just need to implement all the methods that are declared in the interfaces. You can learn about abstract classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and about AWT/Swing painting [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).